# Short story about a man who desperately needs a dime; ending reveals coin slot in his back

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story published before 1985 (I think) and likely included in an anthology (Hugo, Nebula, Sci-Fi Oddities).

From what I recall, the story is about a a man who is desperately seeking a dime from passersby.

He enters a bar and asks anyone if they could spare a dime, not ever giving the reason for his need.

In the end, he keels over dead. The long coat he is wearing flips up to reveal a slot in his back - a place to insert coins.

Comment: Almost certainly not your story, but something similar: http://acidicfiction.com/2015/06/05/coin-op-carter/

Answer (score 17):

**I'm looking for a short story published before 1985 (I think) and likely included in an anthology (Hugo, Nebula, Sci-Fi Oddities).**

The story is ["Rundown"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59968) by [Robert Lory](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1174), first published in [*If*, May 1963](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58800+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/1963-05_IF_modified#page/n75/mode/2up)), reprinted in the 1966 anthology [*Science Fiction Oddities*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?29122) edited by [Groff Conklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_Conklin).

**From what I recall, the story is about a a man who is desperately seeking a dime from passersby.**

> A dime. One dime!

**He enters a bar and asks anyone if they could spare a dime, not ever giving the reason for his need.**

> "Please, a dime, I need a dime, that's all I—"
>
> "A *dime?*" George laughed. "For what, a cup of coffee? This is a high-class place. Beer costs fifteen cents here."
>
> Shorty joined in with a snort. "Maybe he wants to call his girl."
>
> "I *need* the dime," the man said, leaning on the bar for support.
>
> "A matter of real life and death, huh?" George said.
>
> "Yes. Look . . . here. I have two cents, you take them."
>
> Pete looked suspiciously at the two coins. "We don't sell anything that costs two cents."
>
> "You take the two cents, but give me a dime. *Please*."

**In the end, he keels over dead.**

Not dead, but he is knocked out by a punch:

> George needed no warning. He had seen the man eying his money, and he had hoped for just such a move. With a right fist to the side of the man's head, George took revenge for a bad day's work.
>
> The man lay very still on the floor.

**The long coat he is wearing flips up to reveal a slot in his back - a place to insert coins.**

The coin slot is in his chest:

> "Holy cow," said Shorty. It was the first sound any of the three had made after the man had left, fifteen minutes before.
>
> George stared into the mirror behind the bar, seeking some mighty truth in his own reflection. "He says . . . he says *Unbutton my shirt*, and then . . ."
>
> George fondled some coins in his hand. "Then he takes that crazy dime, a plain old, regular, crazy dime . . ."
>
> Pete poured himself a Scotch. "What kind of guy is it, anyway," he said, "who walks around with a slot in the middle of his chest that he puts dimes into?"
>
> "Yeah," said George, "and who *ticks*, yet?"

Comment: That's it! Ironically, I kinda feel like the character in the story...much better now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! You can mark the answer ["accepted"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark next to it.